# Rotated Side Header Overlaps with Image Content for Nicematrix

Tags: floats, rotating, nicematrix

I want these two (images [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXxyi.png) and [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXxyi.png)) to be arranged in `2 X 1 array` with rotated `side headers` but my `side header (sd = 1 nad sd = 3) overlap with the` y-axis labels` of the images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{7em}{%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 1}$}
                \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{image1.png}
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{7em}{%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 3}$}
                \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{image2.png}
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \caption{Figure of figures}
        \label{figg1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output that has overlapping effects

[image: output that has overlapping effects]

Here is a model of what I want

[image: model of what I want].

I want the `rotated side header` to be vividly separated to the left from the `y-axis label` in the images.

I will want the aim to be achieved with `nicematrix` package.

Comment: You may use two columns, one for the text and one for the image, instead of one column.

Comment: The idea will be great but I have tried putting the second column like this `\begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}l}[hvlines]` it did not run. Please help me with the two columns.

Comment: Error massage: `Package nicematrix Error: The preamble of your environment {NiceTabular}(nicematrix) announces 2 columns but you use only 1. }` as I use `\begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}}[hvlines]` instead of `\begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}l}[hvlines]`

Comment: Most probably, you forgot to insert the column separator (`&`).

Comment: Thanks, it works.